# Integrate Marklogic Envision and DataHubFramework

Tags: marklogic

I tried to integrate the data from DHF to envision 1.0.5. (I know there is v2.0.2, but I think the basic view is same).
All I could get to is viewing the entity on the "Connect" section.

A tutorial with an example of this tool would be useful.

Some questions like below aren't seen in the documentation as well. Any help in answering below is appreciated.

1. Is this tool production ready?
2. Can this be used in place of other visualization tools like Neo4j,
   Graphviz etc?
3. If the underlying database is not a triple store/graph db, can it
   still integrate and show the content in the "Explore" section?
4. Can we use this tool to create RDF triples too?

Answer (score 5):

There's documentation https://marklogic-community.github.io/envision/

There are also tutorials available on youtube for each of the components.  Here's a playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyLys5HTD_bCAT2gUnf8v_tDwuk6Vu3d2

Envision works with DHF 5.2.x.  Not sure why you're using an old version of Envision when you know there's a more recent one available. If you run into any issue, the first thing we'd do is recommend you use the latest version before logging any bugs.

To your questions:

1. Yes.Though I'd be interested in your definition of "production ready" https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61726/define-production-ready
2. Envision provides a visualization for multi-model data in a MarkLogic Data Hub. In Explore, entities/nodes are documents in MarkLogic. The relationships between them are triples.  Though the data looks like a graph, it's not just triples.

That said, the Know tab provides a visualization for just triples. (Just load a bunch of triples into MarkLogic and you can view them in Know.)

3. Envision works with the MarkLogic Data Hub.  The assumption is that it is providing visualizations on top of MarkLogic.  Upload assumes you're loading data to a MarkLogic Data Hub. Connect is a visual editor for Entity Services descriptors and TDEs in the hub. Integrate creates flows and steps for integrating data in the hub. Explore is a view within the Data Hubs Staging and Final DBs.  There is a graph view, and a grid view (no relationships required). There is also a mastering workspace to provide Human In The Loop (HITL) review of entities identified with a Notify action during a Match step.  Assuming you integrated data in MarkLogic, you can use Envision. If you have a different DB in mind, you should probably look at a different application.
4. Currently Envision doesn't provide an option to create triples only, though we've thought of updating Connect to provide this option (instead of generating ES descriptors and TDEs, provide a button to mash that generates triples only for the model you've drawn).  But there's a tool already for that (take a look at gra.fo)  and Envision isn't aiming to be an ontology editor, just to allow you to create a model for your data in MarkLogic that allows you to integrate it and Connect it with the world of triples. Triples themselves however are better managed in a tool purpose built for that like Stanford's Protege or some such.